# External Scrolling

Tags: python, scroll, external

I have a friend who doesn't have a mouse that can scroll who asked me to write him a program that could scroll in other windows. I'm most familiar with Python and was thinking of something that could bind certain keys to scroll. Are there any libraries or any way to scroll in an another window, like a webpage or text editor?

Comment: Hm .. there are the keys cursor up/down and page up/down.

Comment: Windows? Linux? OSX?  You'll need to be much more specific, and you are likely to get voted down for not at least showing that you have tried something.  This is very inspecific.

Comment: It's Snow Leopard OSX 10.6.6 and he wants fine scrolling, not moving the cursor around, haven't a clue why it really matters much though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) might do the job for you.